# Allow Limited Admin rights (No Read) to provide others Access

Tags: permissions, access

I have a SharePoint Access/Security issue that I'm trying to figure out...

Requirement:
The "Service Desk" team needs to be able to give users access to various Sites and Lists etc.

The Issue:
The "Service Desk" team are NOT aloud to be able to open or even Read the contents of the Documents as the main list(s) in question are Financial and HR related Documents.

So, basically they need to Give Access, without the ability to Read the documents themselves.

If you have a Solution or Link for me that would be great!

Comment: What you are trying to say is Service Desk team must be ablke to grant others access, but the Service desk team should not be able to read any list

Comment: Bingo! That's exactly what I am Looking for, and in such few words. :)

Comment: Sorry, I left something out. The basic Farm hierarchy for this scenario is... - Farm = Parent Company, Sites = Chains (Child Companies), Document Library = Topic, Document Library Folder = Branch Code (1 folder per branch)... The Last Permission level sits on the Folder - This is where the the access is required. Anyone with Access to the Folder, has access to the files contained. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Are you willing to write code to acheive this? may be a custom webpart in a page?